# Cordova cross origin not working

Tags: cordova, cors

I had my project working perfectly for a while, and I have this line in my config.xml :

```
<access origin="*" />
```

Until yesterday I'm not sure what exactly happened but I can't get CORS ajax request from my cordova project on android. All my requests are made locally there's no webview and my code works fine when I use the build from the phonegap website. So this must be something wrong with my cordova configuration.

What can be the reason for this ? All I can find on google is to add the `origin="*"` to the config.xml but I already have it. 
Any suggestions are appreciated. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue a few weeks back after I removed a plugin from my project (because it also removed the internet permission). 
So you might need to check your AndroidManifest.xml if it contains the following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: great catch! you saved my hours of efforts!